# I am using Rejex instead of Pattern that is replica in C#. but I am unable to get replica of methods matcher() matches() in Rejex

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a syntax difference in writing regular expressions in C# and Java?

How can I have the equivalence of the following code in c#

```
Pattern.matcher(word).matches();
```

where in pattern I have `"\\.|[!?]+"`

There is no `Pattern` Class in C#.

I am using Rejex instead of Pattern that is a replica in C#. but I am unable to get a replica of methods `matcher()` `matches()` in Regex.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

Comment: The syntax is mostly the same (there are some small difference in lookbehind, but it's not related to the question). If you are asking about C#, probably check out this site: http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: `Regex.Matches(word,pattern)`

Comment: Thanks, But now I am having problem i.e. the RE = "\\.|[!?]+" in java return false on word "Dr." but in C# it is returns true. But according to my requirement it should be false as it is happening in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given almost every regular expression implementation has differences I would expect that .NET and Java regular expressions are different. You can check out their documentation (for .NET it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)).

A better source would be Friedl's *Mastering Regular Expressions* which covers the details of how different regex engines (including Java and .NET differ).

To match a regular expression in .NET use the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class. Eg.:

```
Match results = myRegex.Match(myString);
```

where the instance of [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) includes all the details of the single (as above) or multiple (using method [`Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx)) matches and any captures. Or with its property [`Success`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success.aspx) false of course.

---

If by `rejex` you mean [*Rejex the JavaScript regular expression editor*](http://rejex.heroku.com/) then that'll be using the JavaSript regular expression engine; which is different again.

Comment: Thanks All. But now I am having problem i.e. the RE = "\\.|[!?]+"
in java return false on word "Dr." but in C# it is returns true.
But according to my requirement it should be false as it is happening in java

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad Does the Java method (RTFM) only match a complete string? The .NET engine will match part, and that regex will match anything with at least a period in it. Try `^\\.[!?]+$`.

Comment: Yahooo it worked thanks Alot ... I am very thankfull to you. :D

Comment: I am still having problem kindly help me.
In java the word ".2.1" returns false on RE =  "\\.|[!?]+"
While in C# the Word ".2.1" returns true on RE = "^\\.[!?]+$".
It means these Regular Expression are not equal kindly help me. I am waiting for your reply

Comment: @OsamaJameelAhmad Have you got an answer to the question in my previous comment? (I don't write Java so I don't know the details: you'll need to do some work yourself.)